# Will a Dell docking station work with other brands?

Tags: laptop

So I'm looking into buying a docking station for my laptop. Something connected via USB 3.0.
Google was no help so here I am.

I own a custom built laptop by Clevo/Sager. This brings up the question of:
Will branded docking stations like [this one](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA4A04AN6446) work on other brands, or exclusively for the brand they were made for?
I can't find any 'universal' ones that fit my needs and budget, and Sager doesn't make their own.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

*This* one should, though that's not always the case.

USB 3.0 type B input, video's done through an internal USB 3.0 chip (rather than passing through - so not something you'd want to use for something like gaming). There's a slight chance you'd need additional drivers for things like displaylink but that's trivial

If a dock connected through a non standard connector, then you'd have issues.

Answer (score 1):

That's the confusing part of calling such a device a *dock* or even a *port replicator* when it doesn't even look and work like a dock and doesn't replicate existing ports or hardware features.

Think of it as the following external devices combined into one fed by a small laptop PSU*:

- a USB hub
- a USB LAN interface
- a USB sound card / DAC
- a USB (pseudo) graphics adapter (the DisplayLink chip) to feed connected monitors

I used one from HP on several non-HP devices and self-built computers. (Tablets and smartphones are supposed to work too, but I don't know the requirements, except a USB 3.0 port.) All of the components/devices should be able to work independently, which is what I found out when I tried mine on Ubuntu while there were no drivers for USB 3.0 devices back then, everything except graphics was working.

These also usually don't charge your laptop.

*N.B.: mine draws a considerable amount of power and gets quite hot.

Comment: Amusingly, I was thinking of the *other* sort of HP docks at my last workplace with a non standard connector, and the bottom dock connectors on my old thinkpad laptop(s)

Comment: Yep. It's a USB hub with delusions of grandeur. It shouldn't be called a "docking station" unless it connects to the laptop's internal PCE-E bus.